# При попытке зарегистрировать пользователя выдает ошибку , по возможности помогите с регистрацией

Tags: html, css, python, django

Ввожу все данные логин, почту пароль а выводит ошибку. И вообще помогите с регистрацией и заходом на сайт можете написать готовый код желательно пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

views.py

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    from .forms import LoginForm
    from .forms import UserRegistrationForm

    def RegisterFormView(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
                new_user.save()
                return render(request, 'register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
        else:
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', {'user_form': user_form})




    def Login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                user = authenticate(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py не главный

```
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

    urlpatterns =[
        path('register', views.RegisterFormView, name='RegisterFormView'),
        path('login', views.Login, name='Login'),
    ]
```

forms.py (сам создал)

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']




class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

login.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}


{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

registre.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Create an account</h1>
    <p>Please, sign up using the following form:</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create my account"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Главный urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.context_processors import static
from django.urls import path, include
from RapterGames import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('news.urls')),
    path('news/',include('news.urls')),
    path('shop/',include('shop.urls')),
    path('projects/',include('projects.urls')),
    path('', include('registration.urls')),


]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример регистрации:

***forms.py:***

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].strip()
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Пользователь с таким email уже существует')

        return email
```

***views.py:***

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate


@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {'form': form,
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

***register.html:***

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}">
  <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ email }}">
  <input type="password" name="password1" value="{{ password1 }}">
  <input type="password" name="password2" value="{{ password2 }}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Данный пример делает следующее:
 1. Когда приходит POST запрос, проверяет данные, в том числе уникальность email.
 2. Если данные верны, регистрирует и логинит пользователя, иначе отправляет форму с данными назад.

*Примечание: данный код очень далёк от идеала, это учебный пример. После понятия принципа, рекомендую Вам переписать его. Как минимум, советую использовать представления на основе классов ([CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/))*